# Why does my ng-materials "select" element function differently than my HTML5 element?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

Im trying to use the md-input and md-option elements from the ng-materials ui-components.

As an ng-materials object it doesn't work:

```
<md-input-container>
    <md-select ng-model="forcast.selectedCompound">
       <md-option ng-value="compound._id" ng-repeat="compound in forcast.compounds" >
              {{compound.compound_number}}
        </md-option>
    </md-select>
</md-input-container>
```

Using regular html 5 components it does work:

```
<md-input-container>
    <select ng-model="forcast.selectedCompound">
       <option value="{{compound._id}}" ng-repeat="compound in forcast.compounds" >
              {{compound.compound_number}}
        </option>
    </select>
</md-input-container>
```

Because the html5 element works I'm convinced there is something wrong with my ng-materials markup?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `value` attribute in `md-option` instead of `ng-value` with `{{ }}`. check out the offical documentation of [select](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/select).

```
<md-input-container>
<md-select ng-model="forcast.selectedCompound">
   <md-option value="{{compound._id}}" ng-repeat="compound in forcast.compounds" >
          {{compound.compound_number}}
    </md-option>
</md-select>
```

Working example.
http://codepen.io/next1/pen/yOgYVP

Comment: Thanks for the response and punker. I have tried this syntax with the same result. I can click it once(it is highlighted) but then all ng-material components then no longer function. I have a feeling I ran into some compatibility option.

The only major change from your plunk to my code is I'm getting the data async.